# How to apply HTML required in vuejs radio button?

Tags: html

I have two radio button.

```
<div class="col-md-4">Yes : <input id="default_yes" value="1" type="radio" v-model="default"></div>

<div class="col-md-8">No : <input id="default_no" value="0" type="radio" v-model="default"></div>
```

How to apply HTML required in vuejs radio button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `required` with radio, you just need to keep `name` for every input from this group.
This question is not at all about VueJS. It is only about HTML.

```
<input id="default_yes" name="myChoice" value="1" type="radio" v-model="default" required>
<input id="default_no" name="myChoice" value="0" type="radio" v-model="default" required>
```

Comment: Great. Happy to help :) Not only in this case, remember to choose "approved answer". It makes Stack better